# The class inherits two different generic derivations of the same class

Tags: generics, polymorphism, generic-collections, eiffel

What is the proper way of precising the type of an iterable through inheritence.

as inherit FOO[like babar] is not alowed

### FOO

```
class FOO

inherit
    ITERABLE[detachable ANY] -- I know garbage but for DB_RESULT its the case


feature -- Access

    new_cursor: ITERATION_CURSOR[like items.item]
        do
            Result := items.new_cursor
        end

    items: ARRAY[detachable ANY]


end -- class FOO
```

### BAR

```
class BAR

inherit
    FOO -- I know garbage but for DB_RESULT its the case

    ITERABLE[STRING] -- I know garbage but for DB_RESULT its the case


feature -- Access

    new_cursor: ITERATION_CURSOR[like items.item]
        do
            Result := items.new_cursor
        end

    items: ARRAY[STRING]


end -- class FOO
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a formal generic parameter in class `FOO`:

```
class FOO [G]
inherit
    ITERABLE [G]
```

Then, class `BAR` would provide a suitable actual generic parameter:

```
class BAR
inherit
    FOO [STRING]
```

Comment: I was thinking too about this solution, but don't want to give for each l_foo: FOO[detachable  ANY] but maybe the only way is to 'FOO_GENERIC_ANY inherit FOO[detachable ANY]' :(

Comment: @Pipo As far as I know, anchored types are not going to be supported in parent clauses soon, so I do not see a better solution at the moment.